# Adding a extra subquery to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

So i have 2 tables, users and messages

users table

---

uid, username

messages table

---

mid, senderid, receiverid, message, timestamp

The query i have at the moment is retrieving the uid, username and last timestamp of each chat conversation

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

IF (messages.senderid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415', messages.receiverid, messages.senderid) as uid, 

(SELECT username FROM users WHERE uid = IF (messages.senderid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415', messages.receiverid, messages.senderid)) as username, 

MAX(messages.timestamp) as last_timestamp

FROM messages JOIN users ON users.uid = messages.senderid WHERE messages.senderid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415' OR messages.receiverid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415'

GROUP BY 1,2
```

which outputs below

uid | username   | last_timestamp
1   | Developer  | 1601826378

2   | BetaTester | 1601826301

What i need to add to this query is the message field which is based on the last_timestamp i have in the output.

How can the query be updated to include the extra message field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select A.uid, C.username, B.timestamp, B.message from (SELECT DISTINCT 

IF (messages.senderid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415', messages.receiverid, messages.senderid) as uid,

MAX(messages.mid) as max_mid

FROM messages WHERE messages.senderid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415' OR messages.receiverid = '5e9b95786a71f8.25790415'

GROUP BY 1) A join messages B on A.max_mid = B.mid join users C on A.uid = C.uid
```

Comment: Thanks but when i tried this i get "Can't group on 'max_mid'"

Comment: @TRicks, Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confuse, since you already got last_timestamp why don't just left join message table again.

```
left JOIN messages m2 on last_timestamp = m2.timestamp and mid = m2.mid
```

and just select message column

```
select m2.message
```